# how to create ListView or TableView like calendar in blackberry

Tags: listview, blackberry, view, calendar, tableview

how can i create a view like calendar in blackberry and every list have a different color (example : blue for odd row and white for even-numbered row).

I want a structure like below

text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text 
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text
text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text

other sample, like an image in this link --> http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/14535/

i use blackberry jde 4.7.
thanks

Comment: GridFieldManager supports 4.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
int k;
LabelField l;

GridFieldManager grid = new GridFieldManager(9,4,0); //First parameter for row,second for column
    for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
        k=i%2;
         if(k!=0){
             l=new LabelField(""+i)
             {
                 public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                 {
                 graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                 super.paint(graphics);
                 }
             } ;
         }else{
             l=new LabelField(""+i)
             {
                 public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                 {
                 graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                 super.paint(graphics);
                 }
             } ;
         }

         grid.add(l);

    }
     grid.setColumnPadding(30);
     grid.setRowPadding(30);
     add(grid);
```

Comment: i can't use GridFieldManager because i use blackberry jde 4.7. if i try your codes i must create GridFieldManager Class. can you give me sample code for jde 4.7?